# what does it mean to assign a scanf statement to a variable?

Tags: c, scanf

I have recently seen an answer that went over my head,
the guy wrote this piece of code and it had the value of 1.
`cr` is an integer.

```
cr = scanf("%d %.2f",&x,&y)
```

so how can you do so? and why does it give out 1?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? Look for the `RETURN VALUE` section.

Comment: google 'man scanf'

Comment: If it's returning `1`, you didn't type input that matched the pattern.

Comment: Did you look for documentation on scanf and what its return value is?  Was the documentation over your head?

Comment: `%.2f` should be `%f` (assuming `float y;`). Confusing with output spec of `printf`. The two functions `scanf` and `printf` have some similarities in their format specs, but they are different. The function `scanf` gave out 1 because it was unable to convert for the second target.

Comment: or `%2f` . The `.` causes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are obviously gonna get 1 due to the fact there is a problem in that `scanf` statement. You need to remove `.2` from there as @weathervane has stated.

```
cr = scanf("%d %.2f",&x,&y)
```

to this:

```
cr = scanf("%d %f",&x,&y)
```

When you print `cr`, you will get a value of 2 instead of 1. You add another var to scan in that `scanf` statement and print it, you will see a value of 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int x, cr, z;
    float y;

    cr = scanf("%d %f %d",&x,&y, &z);
    printf("%d\n", cr);
}
```

**Output:**

```
56
5
2
3
```

As you could see, `cr` is storing the number of var being used.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for scanf is

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...)
```

The function returns an integer which tells you how many arguments were successfully read. So, here you have:

```
int cr = scanf("%d %.2f", &x, &y);
```

You have 2 arguments ( x and y ) so cr would be 2 if both were successfully read. But you are getting cr = 1. That means that 1 of the arguments has not been successfully read.

As @narusin points out, this is because the format specifier **%.2f** is wrong. If you were using gcc to compile, it would tell you so with a warning (line 3):

```
tmp $ gcc scanf_t.c -o scanf_t
scanf_t.c: In function ‘main’:
scanf_t.c:9:2: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format     [-Wformat=]
n = scanf("%d %.2f", &x, &y);
^
scanf_t.c:9:2: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

To read a floating point number, the format specifier should just be **%f**.